# netcat not listening on desired port

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, netcat

When I want to listen on desired port on one server, I use netcat ie:

```
nc -l  8888
```

Then I can verify the server is actually listening on that port:

```
netstat -tlnp | grep 8888
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2984/nc
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      2984/nc
```

Those steps worked for centos 7, OpenVZ server. However if I perform the same steps on KVM debian 7 i can't see the server listening on port 8888. What could possibly be blocking netcat to listen on that port? Any ideas how can I debug this and get to the core problem?

Comment: you run netcat in the VM, and check on the host? Of course it will not work, these are two separate machines after all.

Comment: no, i only have access to kvm machine.

Comment: how is the machine set up? you give no details there

Comment: @dyasny what setup do you excactly mean?

Comment: The KVM machine, especially the networking part. Is it using NAT, bridge, macvtap, vmfex, ...?